# not able to set BAND FREQ using AT$QCBANDPREF=1,"27,28"

Tags: at-command, modem

i used following AT command to list all available freq. band
My modem device is from QUALCOMM INCORPORATED

AT$QCBANDPREF=?

modem replied with

```
1.BC0_A"
"2.BC0_B"
"3.BC0"
"4.BC1"
"5.BC3"
"6.BC4"
"7.BC5"
"8.GSM_DCS_1800"
"9.GSM_EGSM_900"
"10.GSM_PGSM_900"
"11.BC6"
"12.BC7"
"13.BC8"
"14.BC9"
"15.BC10"
"16.BC11"
"17.BC12"
"18.BC14"
"19.BC15"
"20.BC16
"21.GSM_450"
"22.GSM_480"
"23.GSM_750"
"24.GSM_850"
"25.GSM_RGSM_900"
"26.GSM_PCS_1900"
"27.WCDMA_I_IMT_2000"
"28.WCDMA_II_PCS_1900"
"29.WCDMA_III_1700 "
"30.WCDMA_IV_1700"
"31.WCDMA_V_850"
"32.WCDMA_VI_800 "
"33.WCDMA_VII_2600"
"34.WCDMA_VIII_900"
"35.WCDMA_IX_1700"
"36.WLAN_US_2400 "
"37.WLAN_JAPAN_2400"
"38.WLAN_EUROPE_2400"
"39.WLAN_SPAIN_2400"
"40.WLAN_FRANCE_2400 "
"41.WLAN_US_5000"
"42.WLAN_JAPAN_5000"
"43.WLAN_EUROPE_5000"
"44.WLAN_SPAIN_5000"
"45.WLAN_FRANCE_5000 "
"46.Any"
```

But unfortunately i am not able to set any of this value. I am getting ERROR 
i tried

```
$QCBANDPREF =1, “27,28”
```

Comment: you realize that qualcomm is a huge corporation and has released just a few different "modems"? saying you have a qualcomm modem is like saying you've got a "Ford" and asking for specific details on how to replace a part on it. Plus, note your quotes: `“”` are useless in programming - don't use a word processor to edit your code. use `"`.

Comment: lolz.. this command is being support by modem . AT+CLAC(will list all AT commands being supported by your modem). my question is that are the possible reasons of getting error when i am trying to lock freq 
using $QCBANDPREF =1, “27,28”